# How to get inner directive model values from outer directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to put together few smaller directives to build the larger directive. What is best way to do it as directives will have to communicate, yet not conflict with one another. I put together smaller example that shows what I mean. So given the code below how can I access `aaa` from withing `bbb` without setting `scope : false` on `bbb` directive?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="aaa.html">

                <div ng-form name="loginFields">

                    <input ng-model="aaa" type="text" name="bbb" />

                </div>

            </script>

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="bbb.html">

                <form name="rankings" novalidate>

                    <pre>{{aaa}}</pre>

                    <div aaa></div>

                </form>

            </script>

        <div bbb></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive("aaa", ["loginService",
    function(loginService) {
        return {
            templateUrl: "aaa.html",
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            }
        };
    }
]);


app.directive("bbb", [

    function(rankingsService, $rootScope) {

        return {
            templateUrl: "bbb.html",
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {  
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. define parent controller for both (for example in that ng-app div).
   define the shared items in the parent controller.
   Both directives should NOT use isolated scope (that way, they can see whats in the parent scope).
   your done.
   actually if only aaa changes the data, you can keep it isolated and have bbb see the data.
   but you will need in aaa scope definition to define 2 way binding (scope: {myvar: '='})
2. define parent controller for both (for example in that ng-app div).
   when aaa changes the data (use $scope.$watch or something), emit an event ($scope.$emit('my event', myData);
   have parent scope catch the event and broadcast down a different event ($scope.$broadcast('my event2', myData)
   have bbb listen to event 2 to fetch the data ($scope.$on('my event2', function (event, myData){})